# Why did the sync speed of the geth node drop?

Tags: go-ethereum, nodes, prysm

my node synchronization speed has dropped a lot. If earlier 2048 blocks were stably imported in a couple of seconds, now (blocks from five years ago) the speed dropped to 30-60 blocks in 8 seconds. I run the node with the command:

`geth --datadir=/ethereum/execution --maxpeers=500 --syncmode=snap --http --http.api eth,net,engine,admin,web3`

I also tried syncmode=full, it didn't affect the speed in any way. What could be the matter? I use Prism as a beacon client, maybe that's the reason?

Comment: What network did you chose? I have noticed a significant drop in speed of mining transactions on ```goerly``` testnet in November. It happened shortly after ```the Merge``` when many test chains had been dropped. I still do not know details, but think it was caused by migration of all testnets users to the Goerly and another one officially supported testnet. Dev team might over secure yourself by adding extra nodes and weeks later remove them to optimize the costs. Just thinking.

Comment: @Gleichmut there are no arguments specified in the geth launch command, which means the network is ethereum mainnet